# Holding shift+ctrl then release one each doesn't raise KeyUp event?

Tags: windows, winforms

In my custom control, I override OnKeyUp event handler.

When I press Ctrl key only, then lease it, the keyUp event fired, it's ok.

When I press Shift key only, then lease it, the keyUp event fired, it's ok.

But when I press both Ctr+Shift keys, then lease one by one, for example, holding Ctrl+shift first, then release Shift key while still holding the Ctrl or vice versa.

--> KeyUp never raise??? even I release ctrl after that, no keyUp raised also.

Please help.

Comment: I believe I used OnKeyPress in the past

Comment: Can you please post some code for this part of your program?

Comment: I figured out that it's because Shift+Ctrl trigger another program in my computer. But how to know that another program catch this key strokes? How to access it after another program finish processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because other program accessed at lower level hook and prevent event to fire